# Laravel 5.4 send Email with gmail

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail

I'm trying to send Emails from google but couln't make it yet. I did everything I've found by searching through google but it still won't work.

My Mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'blablabla'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

my .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I also allowed "Less secure Apps" on the gmail settings.

The Mail-Code works perfect, I've tried it out before on mailtrap.io. But if I change it to google I only get errors.

Thats my Code for sending Mail:

```
    \Mail::to('hardcodededmail@gmail.com')->send(new NewThread($thread));
```

And thats the error:

(1/1) ErrorException

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Can someone help me there?

Comment: Have a look over this [issue](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/368)

Comment: thanks for that! That helped me. I'm programming on localhost and if a new thing works, I put it into my live webpage. I couln't send mails because of working on localhost. I used the same code now on my live webpage and it worked perfect. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for me:

```
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="ssl"
```

Also make sure to generate an app password if you're using 2FA.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use TLS or SSL then.

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
```

Change both to:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),
```

Then run:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

This should do the job